# Парсинг в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests, beautiful-soup

Нужно узнать максимальное количество страниц на сайте https://garagetools.ru/catalog/prochie-rashodniki, используя `requests` и `beautifulsoup`.

Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ссылка на последнюю станицу пагинации есть в `html` ответа в `span` с классом `last`.
Выделить ее можно с помощью кода:

```
soup.find('span', class_='last').find('a')['href']
```

`soup.find` вернет строку с `url`:

```
/catalog/prochie-rashodniki?page=11
```

Номер последней страницы, соответственно:

```
int(last_page_link.replace('/catalog/prochie-rashodniki?page=', ''))
```

Код в функции:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def garagetools():
    url = 'https://garagetools.ru/catalog/prochie-rashodniki'
    r = requests.get(url)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    last_page_link = soup.find('span', class_='last').find('a')['href']

    page_count = int(last_page_link.replace('/catalog/prochie-rashodniki?page=', ''))

    return page_count
```

Comment: а как можно узнать кол-во страниц, если  ссылки на последнюю страницу нету в span с классом last? https://eightify.app/summary/miscellaneous/page-911

Comment: можно при помощи get-запросов и добавлением каждого следующего номера в конец адреса страницы. Но сервер не заблокирует за это?

Comment: last page - 1110